# cancel request in beforefilter() in PHP

Tags: php, acl, before-filter

I'm using CakePHP , CAS for Authentication and ACL for Authorization.
If the user donot have permission to view the page, i need to flash a message stating Not permitted OR redirect to another page.

Ex: If the user is viewing /users/view/1 .Now the user requests /users/delete/1. The user donot have permission to delete. So I want to display a flash message on the page he requested from (/users/view/1).

In my app_controller, i have the following function:

```
function beforeFilter() {
  $this->__initPhpCas();
  if (isset($_SESSION['loggedIn'])){
    if(!$this->Acl->check(.....){
        //User do not have permission to view the page.
        // Need to cancel this request and flash a message 
   }
  }
```

Any suggestions are appreciated

Final answer is

```
function beforeFilter() {
      $this->__initPhpCas();
      if (isset($_SESSION['loggedIn'])){
        if(!$this->Acl->check(.....){
            //User do not have permission to view the page.
            // Need to cancel this request and flash a message 
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('You are not authorized to view this page.', true));
        $this->redirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
       }
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to [redirect](http://book.cakephp.org/view/425/redirect) use `$this->redirect();` and [add a message](http://book.cakephp.org/view/400/setFlash) by using `$this->Session->setFlash();`.  I have included links to show you.

EDIT:

I would recommend setting the flash message then doing the redirect.  Then on the redirected page, display the flash message with `$session->flash();`.

EDIT2:

Since you are not wanting to do a redirect you will need to do something like this.

```
function view() {
    if($this->Acl->check(.....){
        //display the page and continue with the view action
    }
    else {
        $this->Session->setFlash("You do not have access to use this feature");
    }
}
```

EDIT 3:

[Try this](http://cakephp.1045679.n5.nabble.com/Stop-code-execution-in-beforeFilter-and-render-a-view-td1312253.html). Take a look at the last post in the link.

Edit 4: Try using [deny()](http://book.cakephp.org/view/383/deny)

Edit 5:

If I understand you correctly you want to use beforeFilter to check if they have access and if not then don't continue running the actions.  CakePHP doesn't really allow this but a work around is.

```
function beforeFilter() {
    if($this->Acl->check(.....){
        //display the page and continue with the view action
    }
    else {
        $this->Session->setFlash("You do not have access to use this feature");
        $this->params['action'] = "failedCheck";
    }
}

function failedCheck() {
    //blah blah blah
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The problem i have when redirect is, I want to make the user stay in the same page where he requested from. For example he requests /user/delete from /user/view. In my beforefilter the request is /user/delete. How i can get the "/user/view" url - the one from where he requested ? So dat i can redirect him to /user/view

Comment: I was unable to figure out a way to just cancel it so what I ended up doing is checking in my action if they were authenticated and if so then I would continue with the processing of the page.  If not then I would not display the info that the user request but instead display the flash message.  See answer for example

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The "edit 2" idea works, but there is a lot of code redundancy. I have to perform this check for all the methods, so i was thinking if i could somehow do it in the beforefilter(), then it be more single point and modular.

Comment: Thank you Joster. But it behaves as the last comment says. "Returning false keeps the flow running (cake will execute further 
actions).".

Comment: Hi Joster, Deny is to set(kinda) permissions. The action "delete" is already denied. When i perform Acl->check(..). It returns false, as it is denied.

Comment: @metalhawk ... I am sorry I miss understood your first comment.  The redirect will work fine but you just wanted to get the url the user came from.  Use the `$this->redirect($this->referrer());`  This will redirect the user to the page they came from.  But before doing the redirect I would do $this->Session->setFlash("message"); so they can see why they were redirected.

Comment: Thank you for your time Joster. $this->referrer() did not work. But $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] worked. Thanks again. :)